# Do simcards leave marks on android phones?

Tags: sim-card

Question: Is there a way that i can find out whats happening? I mean is there a way that i can find a track that she uses another SIM card time to time. Do SIM cards leave any marks on the phone, in the documents or somewhere?

Comment: I find the first sentence quite unclear. *Find out what's happening?*

Comment: @Death Mask Salesman read that with next sentence. He is probably thinking that his girlfriend/wife is cheating on him or something similar and she uses second sim card.  However sim cards don't leave marks in documents, but they do leave a mark on IMEI, that works one to many, so if you are in law enforcement you'll know where to look. Good luck with paranoia

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје While it would be a mildly interesting question per se, I fear that its context is similar to the one described in [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/182235/152843) other question. I personally don't think that we should answer questions tied to sensitive aspects of the asker's life.

Comment: @Death Mark Salesman  Well, the reason which made my first sentence "find out whats happening bla bla" look nonsense is because its edited by a moderator. There was a short explanation before that sentence. I asked this question because i think i see some signs.  She is not my wife, she is my girlfriend. I don't want to break up with her before i know the truth .If she uses another one and not telling me that in someway, just want to split our ways with her.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is indeed a way to get notified when a new SIM card has been inserted into an Android device.

Some manufacturers has it built in their phones, some antivirus softwares have this feature. There are also many apps on Google Play that provide this functionality.

I don't know if it is legal to share such softwares here or not. Moderators can tell if so or not and I'll share some of them. Anyway, Google is your best friend.